# http.client.ResponseNotReady: Idle

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, http.client

I'm trying to learn how to code with http.client but a simple code ends in this error and I don't know what to do.

```
import http.client

conn=http.client.HTTPSConnection('www.google.com')
res=conn.getresponse()
print(res.status,res.reason)
```

and the error it gives me is:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:/Users/A/PycharmProjects/untitled/testung.py", line 9, in 
>   res=conn.getresponse() File
>   "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py",
>   line 1312, in getresponse raise ResponseNotReady(self.__state)
>   http.client.ResponseNotReady: Idle –

Comment: Your error trace doesn't match your code. Why is get passed as an argument in the getresponse method?

Comment: you are right i'm sorry i meant to say this 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/A/PycharmProjects/untitled/testung.py", line 9, in <module>
    res=conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 1312, in getresponse
    raise ResponseNotReady(self.__state)
http.client.ResponseNotReady: Idle`

Comment: Thanks. See my update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From python official documentation:

> HTTPConnection.getresponse()  Should be called after a request is
>   sent to **get** the response from the server. Returns an HTTPResponse
>   instance.

[**Source**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPConnection.getresponse)

So changing your code to this

```
import http.client

conn=http.client.HTTPSConnection('www.google.com')
conn.request("GET", "/")
res=conn.getresponse()
print(conn)
```

Outputs

```
<http.client.HTTPSConnection object at 0x01DFEEB0>
```